# PyAudio bug on docker container (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I want to install PyAudio on a Docker container (Python 2.7) with a requirement file because I want to use the library "SpeechRecognition".
The problem is that it cannot install PyAudio.... (without PyAudio in the requirement file) it works fine.

The following error comes up in visual studio code: "An error occurred setting up the container." This is 100% related to pyaudio.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

I tried several solutions:

- install it on dockerfile with "RUN pip install pyaudio"
- different versions of pyaudio
- install PyAudio with requirement file

When I install it with !pip install pyaudio this error message comes..

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ...   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-FsZnhG/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=61.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (5 lines):
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=61.0 (from versions: 0.6b1, 0.6b2, 0.6b3, 0.6b4, 0.6rc1, 0.6rc2, 0.6rc3, 0.6rc4, 0.6rc5, 0.6rc6, 0.6rc7, 0.6rc8, 0.6rc9, 0.6rc10, 0.6rc11, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.7.7, 0.7.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7, 0.9.8, 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.5, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7.1, 3.8, 3.8.1, 4.0, 4.0.1, 5.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.5, 5.5.1, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.1, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.0.4, 8.1, 8.2, 8.2.1, 8.3, 9.0, 9.0.1, 9.1, 10.0, 10.0.1, 10.1, 10.2, 10.2.1, 11.0, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.3.1, 12.0, 12.0.1, 12.0.2, 12.0.3, 12.0.4, 12.0.5, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.4, 13.0.1, 13.0.2, 14.0, 14.1, 14.1.1, 14.2, 14.3, 14.3.1, 15.0, 15.1, 15.2, 16.0, 17.0, 17.1, 17.1.1, 18.0, 18.0.1, 18.1, 18.2, 18.3, 18.3.1, 18.3.2, 18.4, 18.5, 18.6, 18.6.1, 18.7, 18.7.1, 18.8, 18.8.1, 19.0, 19.1, 19.1.1, 19.2, 19.3, 19.4, 19.4.1, 19.5, 19.6, 19.6.1, 19.6.2, 19.7, 20.0, 20.1, 20.1.1, 20.2.2, 20.3, 20.3.1, 20.4, 20.6.6, 20.6.7, 20.6.8, 20.7.0, 20.8.0, 20.8.1, 20.9.0, 20.10.1, 21.0.0, 21.1.0, 21.2.0, 21.2.1, 21.2.2, 22.0.0, 22.0.1, 22.0.2, 22.0.4, 22.0.5, 23.0.0, 23.1.0, 23.2.0, 23.2.1, 24.0.0, 24.0.1, 24.0.2, 24.0.3, 24.1.0, 24.1.1, 24.2.0, 24.2.1, 24.3.0, 24.3.1, 25.0.0, 25.0.1, 25.0.2, 25.1.0, 25.1.1, 25.1.2, 25.1.3, 25.1.4, 25.1.5, 25.1.6, 25.2.0, 25.3.0, 25.4.0, 26.0.0, 26.1.0, 26.1.1, 27.0.0, 27.1.0, 27.1.2, 27.2.0, 27.3.0, 27.3.1, 28.0.0, 28.1.0, 28.2.0, 28.3.0, 28.4.0, 28.5.0, 28.6.0, 28.6.1, 28.7.0, 28.7.1, 28.8.0, 28.8.1, 29.0.0, 29.0.1, 30.0.0, 30.1.0, 30.2.0, 30.2.1, 30.3.0, 30.4.0, 31.0.0, 31.0.1, 32.0.0, 32.1.0, 32.1.1, 32.1.2, 32.1.3, 32.2.0, 32.3.0, 32.3.1, 33.1.0, 33.1.1, 34.0.0, 34.0.1, 34.0.2, 34.0.3, 34.1.0, 34.1.1, 34.2.0, 34.3.0, 34.3.1, 34.3.2, 34.3.3, 34.4.0, 34.4.1, 35.0.0, 35.0.1, 35.0.2, 36.0.1, 36.1.0, 36.1.1, 36.2.0, 36.2.1, 36.2.2, 36.2.3, 36.2.4, 36.2.5, 36.2.6, 36.2.7, 36.3.0, 36.4.0, 36.5.0, 36.6.0, 36.6.1, 36.7.0, 36.7.1, 36.7.2, 36.8.0, 37.0.0, 38.0.0, 38.1.0, 38.2.0, 38.2.1, 38.2.3, 38.2.4, 38.2.5, 38.3.0, 38.4.0, 38.4.1, 38.5.0, 38.5.1, 38.5.2, 38.6.0, 38.6.1, 38.7.0, 39.0.0, 39.0.1, 39.1.0, 39.2.0, 40.0.0, 40.1.0, 40.1.1, 40.2.0, 40.3.0, 40.4.0, 40.4.1, 40.4.2, 40.4.3, 40.5.0, 40.6.0, 40.6.1, 40.6.2, 40.6.3, 40.7.0, 40.7.1, 40.7.2, 40.7.3, 40.8.0, 40.9.0, 41.0.0, 41.0.1, 41.1.0, 41.2.0, 41.3.0, 41.4.0, 41.5.0, 41.5.1, 41.6.0, 42.0.0, 42.0.1, 42.0.2, 43.0.0, 44.0.0, 44.1.0, 44.1.1)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=61.0
  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.3.4 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Why are you still using python 2.7? :)

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper good question! :D i MUST use this version for a project..

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do you know that the error is related to pyaudio? Do you have any more details about the error?

Comment: @rainbow.gekota Thanks for your answer! :) 

I need PyAudio for the package "SpeechRecognition" --> AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation --> without PyAudio in req file.

I know this because I built the container without PyAudio in the requirements file and the container works, but when I put PyAudio in the requirements file I get a window from visual studio code.

It's so weird... :D